# react-native start EACCESS error for setup_env.sh

Tags: ios, react-native, ulimit

So, I got my first project in ReactNative to run from Windows for Android OS. Took a checkout on a Mac, configured it in an identical manner and as I try to start the react package manager using `react-native start` and get the following error:

```
child_process.js:506
    throw err;
    ^
Error: spawnSync /Users/UserName/Desktop/Path/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/setup_env.sh EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at spawnSync (child_process.js:461:20)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:498:13)
    at Object.run (/Users/UserName/Desktop/Path/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:156:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:117:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I am aware that it only tries to set the ulimit (open file limit) to 2048 which is permissible for non root users. Also tried running the command with sudo giving it root permissions. 
Running `ulimit -a` on the machine revealed an open file limit of 256 and I tried changing the default 2048 to this. Tried increasing it to 4096 as well removing the command altogether. Seems to make no difference what so ever and the error persists.

Created a new project using `react-native init DemoProject` and the packager seems to start within that folder so the issue is something else?

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "React Native",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^0.5.18",
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.39.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-icons": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-md-textinput": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-overlay": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "0.0.40",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Also, if it matters I have sinopia, browserify and yarn installed globally.

To start with, I am not sure if I should add all local dependencies through npm yet again on the Mac and then just copy my code or that should be fine and something else is amiss.

It would be great if I can sort this out without re-adding dependencies. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Simply had to go to my base project directory and run

`chmod -R 777 node_modules`

Comment: I'm facing this issue : `child_process.js:504
    throw err;
    ^

Error: spawnSync /../AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/setup_env.sh EACCES`

Comment: @JacoboKoenig, I'm using ubuntu, it was the problem with my node.
I uninstalled and cleared all the node.js , npm and node folders from the system.

Reinstalled the node again and my problem get solved.

Comment: This Fixed it for me

Answer (score 10):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18324) of npm. Before they fix the bug, you have 2 way to fix the problem:

1. Downgrade the npm version to 5.3.0
2. After npm i react-native, run chmod -R 775 node_modules

Answer (score 5):

in my case the error was with one particular file when i do `react-native link`:

```
Error: spawnSync ~/native-starter-kit/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/setup_env.sh EACCES
```

so i fixed it by running: `chmod +x` on that file.

Answer (score 5):

i have the same issue i tried this and the initial issue got fixed

chmod -R 775 android

Answer (score 0):

As jerry pointed out, this is a bug in NPM. There is a fix available now. You can update NPM with `npm i -g npm`.

I updated to version 5.4.2 (`npm --version`), removed React Native with `npm remove --save react-native` and reinstalled RN with `npm i --save react-native`. This fixed the issue for me.

(As an alternative you might want to try yarn instead of npm.)